# SwiftUI @EnvironmentObject shared in nested view

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm having trouble trying to understand the hierarchy using SwiftUI's @EnvironmentObject wrapper. I've got a ViewModel that needs to be accessed in multiple screens within the app so I've put this code inside the main app file:

```
var chartsModel = ChartsViewModel()
```

Inside the ContentView file generated by Xcode on a new project I have put this inside the ContentView_Previews

```
ContentView().environmentObject(ChartsViewModel())
```

Where I'm now getting confused is I have a view 2 levels deep inside ContentView that needs data from the ViewModel.

```
ContentView()->HomeView()->ChartView()
```

ChartView is a child of HomeView()

I can get ChartView to display the data when in preview mode by using the following code.

```
@EnvironmentObject var viewModel: ChartsViewModel
```

The problem is when previewing HomeView, ContentView or running the app on a device nothing is outputted.

Comment: You should also put ".environmentObject(ChartsViewModel())" in the content view that is defined in your main app file. You probably do somewhere in your main app file ContentView(), that needs to be changed to ContentView().environmentObject(ChartsViewModel())

Answer (score 0):

> Inside the ContentView file generated by Xcode on a new project I have put this inside the ContentView_Previews

You should do this not only in preview provider (which is for Preview mode), but in scene creation as well (so it works for runtime), like

```
@main
struct SwiftUI2App: App {
    var chartsModel = ChartsViewModel()

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView().environmentObject(ChartsViewModel())   // << here !!
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So to clarify. It has to be passed down the hierarchy through each view until each reaches the child view that needs it. Using  ContentView().environmentObject(ChartsViewModel()) then HomeView().environmentObject(ChartsViewModel())?

Comment: No, it is needed only in root view to be available through entire hierarchy, but if you want to transfer it in different hierarchy, say sheet, then you need to inject it in that new content explicitly.

Comment: Ok, and then I would just access it from any view using the following: `@EnvironmentObject var viewModel: ChartsViewModel`?